# getting 503 class cast exception while retrieving data from Google app-engine backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine, entity

I am retrieving data from app engine back-end using endpoints in my android app. In between I changed some properties of table( as in parameters in entity class/ added some extra parameters ) from entity class of app engine project. and again created endpoints lib. Then I run my android project in that case it is giving me following error.

```
503 Service Unavailable
{

        "code" : 503,
         "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "global",

        "message" : "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long",
        "reason" : "backendError"  
    } ],

    "message" : "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long" 
}
```

my code is

```
try{
     CollectionResponseUserMaster userInfoCollection = endpoint.listUserMaster().execute(); 

     for(UserMaster userInfoCollections : userInfoCollection.getItems()) {
     }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

error is on  `CollectionResponseUserMaster userInfoCollection = endpoint.listUserMaster().execute();` line.

entity class parameters are

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long usermasterID;

  private String userID;
  private String employeeID;
  private String mediamasterID;
  private User user;
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private String passwordhintquestion;
  private String passwordhintanswer;
```

Please help me. I am stuck.

Comment: The `usermasterID` is of type Long. What is the data-type of `usermasterID` in the database table  ?

Comment: It is Long in db that's not problem. when I remove extra added fields it works fine but when I put it again it give me error again.